# Printing Batch with Chrome Headless - Process not killed after PDF Report Creation

Tags: iccube

When generating server side PDF Report using Chrome Headless it looks like for each request a chrome.exe process is invoked but it will never be killed. 
This shortly brings to having hundreds of chrome active process and an excessive memory usage.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems related to the version of cdp4j used by icCube. icCube has been updated to use latest 3.x (i.e., 3.0.13) that is fixing that issue.